# Heroku + Material Design Icons + Rails Asset Pipeline stalling

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, material-design

I'm running Angular (with ngMaterial) and a Rails (3.2.x) backend hosted on Heroku. Trying to install Material Design Icons in bower, but they timeout going through the Rails asset precompile step.

Is there a way to install Material Design Icons in a way that is accessible to Angular but also gets through the rails asset pipeline (or uses a CDN hosted set of icons?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the same setup, for material icons I use the Google CDN Link.

Just add it to your index.html.erb (in my case application.html.erb) in the head area:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can than easily use the icons anywhere within your angularJS app like this:

```
<i class="material-icons">search</i>
```